# Getting "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error" in quick start and in example code for bulkReadDocuments

Tags: domino-appdev-pack

Using the *Quick Start* from the **Domino AppDev Pack** documentation, I get an error:

```
(node:46496) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error
    at new DominoDbError (C:\Users\tbahn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@domino\domino-db\src\domino-db-error.js:6:16)
    at wrapError (C:\Users\tbahn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@domino\domino-db\src\requests\grpc\utils\grpc-helpers.js:124:10)
    at client.bulkNote (C:\Users\tbahn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@domino\domino-db\src\requests\grpc\utils\bulk-document.js:157:18)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\tbahn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@domino\domino-db\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:1189:9)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (C:\Users\tbahn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@domino\domino-db\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:564:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\tbahn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@domino\domino-db\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:614:8)
    at callback (C:\Users\tbahn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@domino\domino-db\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:841:24)
(node:46496) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:46496) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Error occurs in line:

```
const response = await database.bulkCreateDocuments(createOptions);
```

Same error I get in the example code of the `database.bulkReadDocuments`.

Comment: Ich hatte einen Fehler in der ServerConfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find better error messages, you should catch the error being thrown.

```
try {
  const response = await database.bulkCreateDocuments(createOptions);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

Comment: Hi Dan, 

thank you. I added the catch, but in another way:

`useServer(serverConfig).then(...).catch(err => console.error(err));`

Comment: I tried to format the last comment as code with line breaks for abou 10 min. :-(

Comment: I spoke with John Curtis today and suggested to add a minimal error handling to the code blocks (each codeblock) in the documentation. The reasoning behind this idea: People new to the subject tend to copy and paste code from the documentation **and** to make mistakes.
With adding minimal error handling, they will faster the information needed to fix their bug.

Comment: In production code I probably use more try-catch-blocks to have a more specific error message and perhaps even could retry after a second (network hickup).

Comment: Not a bad idea.  I'll add it to our backlog.